# I am getting Error In YUI AJAX as NOT AVAILABLE

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using YUI ajax in struts2 . The ajax is returning a map in the form

```
Map<BigInteger ,Map<BigInteger,PartyImpactVO>> resultMap;
```

I am using

```
  if(o.responseText)
   myResults = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(o.responseText);
```

In action class the values are coming but when this statement is reached exception is raising.When i see the error using firebug it is giving `NOT AVAILABLE.`

Till now i worked with lists.They are working properly.What is the wrong here.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Actually whatever the response is coming is in not valid json form.